# Finding Points where two polylines cross in ArcGIS Runtime .NET SDK?

Tags: geometry, line, vb.net, vb, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

I am using ArcGIS SDK for .NET and have a graphic overlay defined on my mapview.  I added two circles to the map (made with polylines) which overlap.  I now need to determine the points at which the two polylines cross.

The GeometryEngine.Intersection() method returns an empty geometry.  The GeometryEngine.Crosses() method returns true.

How can I get the points at which the two polylines cross?

Edit:  Here is some code that I was trying:

```vb
' Get reference to overlay for add operation  
Dim overlay As GraphicsOverlay = Me.ehMapControl.MapView.GraphicsOverlays.Item("NewLocation")  
' Create a graphic object  
Dim myGraphic as Graphic = New Graphic  
' Create a polyline that is a 15 foot circle around "point"  
Dim myEllipseParams As New GeodesicEllipseParameters(point, 15,  LinearUnits.Feet)
myEllipseParams.OutGeometryType = GeometryType.Polyline  
myGraphic.Geometry = GeometryEngine.GeodesicEllipse(myEllipseParams)  
' Add polyline to graphics overlay  
overlay.Graphics.Add(myGraphic)  
' Create a second polyline  
Dim myGraphic2 as graphic = new Graphic  
...  
' Perform an intersection  
Dim intsersect = GeometryEngine.Intersection(myGraphic, myGraphic2)
' Doesn't work (returns an empty geometry)
Dim isCrossing = GeometryEngine.Crosses(myGraphic, myGraphic2)
' Returns true, so the engine knows the two polylines cross
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  If you include a code snippet (there is a **`{}`** button that you can use to format it) you are much more likely to attract potential answerers.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used ArcGIS Runtime .NET SDK yet but looking at the [Help](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/api-reference?T_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Geometry_GeometryEngine.htm) Crosses tests for a spatial relationship and Intersection creates the geometries. In your code snippet you don't show what you did with `myGraphic2`, so may be the root of the problem is there?

But looking at the [VB code sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/api-reference/html/M_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Geometry_GeometryEngine_Intersection.htm) for the Intersection method it shows **geometry** objects being supplied as input parameters, you input **Graphic** objects. May be their code is failing because of that? Try inputting Geometry objects.